# How to align a h2 with a div side by side without colapsing when window changes size?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to align two elements, a h2 and a div side by side without having one of them colapse when the window changes to a smaller size. I've searched the web a bit but found nothing similar that would help and my solutions just wouldn't work so I though here there would be someone able to help me.

So I want it to be displayed like this at all times:

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/912x135q90/631/ZYR7sc.png *(Can't post images sorry!)*

But when window size changes dispite the fact the div should adapt at some point it just breaks to next line:

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/730x144q90/912/yRBpkc.png

Here is my code on this one:

**HTML**

```
<div id='pagetitle'>
    <h2 id='subtitle'>Weapons</h2>
    <div id='hline'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#pagetitle { /* This div is for centering both of the elements. */
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#subtitle {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #72c9b9;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
}

#hline {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #72c9b9;
    width: 70%;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 4px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

So this is it guys, any sugestions? Thanks in advance.

*cs.almeida*

Comment: The best answer depends on what you're trying to achieve. If you just want an extended line, a `<div>` may not be the right way to go. If that line is a placeholder for other content (and if it's important to you that the content never exceeds with width of the page, thereby calling a scrollbar), there are several options, like media queries, JS, or calc(), that could give you want you want. (Caveat: calc() won't work on mobile.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way how to do it:

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ILpwE)

```
<div id='pagetitle'>
    <h2 id='subtitle'><span>Weapons</span></h2>
</div>


#pagetitle {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

#subtitle {
  border-bottom: #72c9b9 solid 2px;
  height: 18px;
  display: block;
  color: #72c9b9;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#subtitle > span {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

Comment: This is exacly what I wanted to do, thank you so much for the support anda looks like I've learned some new stuff!

Really greatuf, once again thanks a lot!